# Path detection in image

Tags: c#, computer-vision

I have to detect path from an image for an obstacle detection app. Can anyone suggest any technique for doing so? I have searched a lot but can't find anything relevant.

Comment: We need more details. At minimum you should provide a sample input image, and the expected output.

Comment: Have you got any other information that would be useful for this, and maybe anything else that you may have tried already.

Answer (score 0):

You have not give enough information about your problem but to start you can use Flood Fill algorithm to mark paths using connected pixel values. Check [this](http://lodev.org/cgtutor/floodfill.html) link.  Opencv computer vision library has good functions to flood fill algorithm.